# Dynamic printing of class and function

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner to xcode and want a dynamic printing of which function are being executed.

So I want a function that would display something like

```
functionExecuted() executed in ClassName
```

That would grab the function name and class name dynamically.
I have something like this already:

```
class MyViewController: ViewController {
    func appActivity() {
        var class: String = "MyViewController"
        println("\(___FUNCTION___) executed in \(class)")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Etc. code
        appActivity()
    }
}
```

Which would run the appActivity() function when the view was loaded. But this would have the output of:

```
appActivity() executed in MyViewController
```

When I am looking for:

```
viewDidLoad() executed in MyViewController
```

I want to retain not having appActivity take any input parameters. Also, instead of defining the class name explicitly, have it dynamically get the name of the class the function is in.

I know this might not be the best way of accomplishing this but it is more about learning and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you do this in an extension. Extensions are perhaps the highlight of Swift, IMHO. You can basically decorate methods, not only of your own classes, but other classes, including framework classes. Want to know when the viewDidLoad got called of your superclass? Just create an extension and watch the messages appear in the console.

The other advantages:

- the code is not dirtying up the main class and its logic (whatever that is)
- you could define the extension in a test file so it's automatically there when you are running tests and not at runtime

The Swift Cocoa code is built on extensions in ways that are really inventive, showing some of the intelligence of aspects, and yet the categorical organization of Objective C. When you combine extensions and Protocols, you have Traits.

Answer (score 0):

I use this often.  It can be implemented as a top-level function and is very small.

```
func Log(_ message: String = "", klass: AnyObject, file: String = __FILE__, function: String = __FUNCTION__) {
    NSLog("%@","\(file.lastPathComponent) \(function) \(klass.self) - \(message)")
}
```